# Nodejs redirect in case bad connect to db

Tags: node.js

I need the redirect if app can't connect to db.
I've trying check mongoose.connection.readyState but have "headers already sent" trouble
How do I can in my middleware do the redirect if db connection is not exists?

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  // Some other middleware stuff

  if(mongoose.connection.readyState < 1) {
    //TODO: doing redirect to /db_error
    // res.redirect("/db_error"); <- this will invoke "headers" problem
  }

  next();
});
```

So, how can i solve this? I wanna don't allow interact with my app without db connection.

Comment: Is this the case for some autoscale instnace failure? Otherwise, you might just shot down the whole app, if connection fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [res.redirect](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){

  // Some other middleware stuff

  if(mongoose.connection.readyState < 1 && req.url != "/db_error") {
    res.redirect("/db_error");
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: No, coz "Can't set headers after they are sent" problem

Comment: No, this code doesn's throw any such errors, please test it. Notice the difference between yours and mine. You call next() after the redirect, the code above either redirects or calls next, therefore you don't get that exception.

Comment: The browser do the loop redirect, then crash even with res.end()

Comment: It shouldn't happen now. Please, test again.

Comment: Yea, that helpful. Thank u